# Extend JavaScript Object to init at same time

Tags: javascript, oop

What's the best way to extend a function so that when it's called, it's also new extended class is called.

Take the following class:

```
var class = {}

class.init = function(){
 //do something
};
```

E.g. now extend init:

```
class.init.prototype.extend = function(){
 console.log("hey look at me, I get called too!");
}
```

The idea here is, when class.init() is called, we'd like the extended classes to be automatically called too.  The goal is to extend the class so i.e. like binding a click event to a link but with out modifying anything from the original function.

Comment: Why is that object called "class"? And what do you mean by "extended classes"?

Comment: Just for this example I've used "class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the function with one that also calls the overwritten one:

```
(function (old) {
    class.init = function() {
        console.log("hey look at me, I get called before!");
        var result = old.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log("hey look at me, I get called after!");
        return result;
    };
}(class.init));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-assign `class.init` to a proxy function that calls the original function as well as your new one.

Something like this:

```
var class = {}

class.init = function(){
 //do something
};

(function(){
    var _old = class.init;
    class.init = function(){
        console.log("hey look at me, I get called too!");
        return _old.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic `extend` method that can extend any method not just init:

[Live at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/opucub/4/edit?javascript,console)

```
function Klass(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.staticMethod = function(){console.log('static method at Klass');};
}

Klass.prototype.someMethod = function(){console.log('Klass.someMethod');};

Klass.extend = function(extention){
  function extendMethod(method1, method2){
    var args = arguments;
    var contex = this;
    return function(){
      method1.apply(contex, args);
      method2.apply(contex, args);
    };
  }

  var proto = new Klass();
  var Extended = function(){Klass.apply(this, arguments);};
  for(var key in extention){
    if(typeof proto[key] === 'function' && typeof extention[key] === 'function'){
      var oldMethod = proto[key];
      proto[key] = extendMethod(oldMethod, extention[key]);
    }
  }
  Extended.prototype = proto;
  return Extended;
};




var ExKlass = Klass.extend({
  someMethod: function(){
    console.log('ExKlass.someMethod');
  }
});


var k = new Klass();
var ek = new ExKlass();

k.someMethod();
ek.someMethod();
```